# course_setup in moodle 1.9 but not in moodle 2.2?

Tags: moodle

I am converting moodle plugin from 1.9 to 2.2 and one of the lines in the code is :

```
    /// setup global $COURSE, language and locale
    course_setup($courseid);
```

After looking at the 2.2 code i was unable to find any reference to the course_setup.. how can this line of code be replicated in the 2.2?

Answer (score 0):

```
$PAGE->set_course().
```

**A bit of research**. From the function documentation of `set_course`:

> Set the current course. This sets both $PAGE->course and $COURSE. It
>   also sets the right theme and locale.
>
> Normally you don't need to call this function yourself, require_login
>   will call it for you if you pass a $course to it. You can use this
>   function on pages that do need to call require_login().

According to documentation, the deprecated function `course_setup`:

> Setup all global `$CFG` course variables, set locale and also themes.
>   This function can be used on pages that do not require login
>   instead of `require_login()`

I've looked around some code. In 1.9, you have this code in `course/user.php`:

```
  if (has_capability('moodle/user:viewuseractivitiesreport', $personalcontext) 
          and !has_capability('moodle/course:view', $coursecontext)) {
      // do not require parents to be enrolled in courses ;-)
      course_setup($course);
  } else {
      require_login($course);
  }
```

In Moodle 2.3, the same code fragment is:

```
if (has_capability('moodle/user:viewuseractivitiesreport', $personalcontext) 
       and !is_enrolled($coursecontext)) {
    // do not require parents to be enrolled in courses ;-)
    $PAGE->set_course($course);
} else {
    require_login($course);
}
```